# Python Openpyxl convert CSV to XLSX & removing "$ ," from cells containing numbers

Tags: python, csv, openpyxl, xlsx, file-conversion

I have to read a csv file that's generated by a third party and contains a mixture of strings, integers and prices (sometimes with $ signs) into a XLSX file. This is the sample data that's stored in the csv file, a_test_f.csv, that I've got:

```
ColA,ColB
1,$11.00
2,22
3,"$1,000.56"
4,44
```

and here is the code that I've written. My question is, is this the most efficient way of performing this conversion. Is there an alternative method that would use less processing power / memory? This is especially important given that the real csv file will contain thousands of records and hundreds of columns and the conversion operation will have to be performed tens of thousands of times per day.

```
import csv
import openpyxl

#
# Convert the data in csv file format that contains a mix of
# strings, integers and dollar amounts into xlsx file format
#

csvfile  = 'a_test_f.csv'
xlsxfile = 'new_xlsx_f.xlsx'

wb = openpyxl.Workbook()
ws = wb.active

# remove $ and , from numbers
class Clean:
    def __init__(self, data=''):
        self.__obj = data
    def __repr__(self):
        return f"{self.__obj}"
    def getData(self):
        return self.__obj

    def dollar(self):
        try:
            return Clean(data=self.__obj.replace('$',''))
        except TypeError as err:
            print(err)

    def comma(self):
        try:
            return Clean(data=self.__obj.replace(',',''))
        except TypeError as err:
            print(err)

    def digit(self):
        try:
            float(self.__obj)
            return True
        except ValueError:
            return False            

with open(csvfile) as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter=',', quotechar='"')
    row_count=1
    for row in reader:
        for i in range(len(row)):
            if Clean(data=row[i]).dollar().comma().digit():
                content = float(repr(Clean(data=row[i]).dollar().comma()))
            else:
                content = row[i]                
            ws.cell(row=row_count,column=i+1).value = content
        row_count +=1

wb.save(xlsxfile)

print('Finished!')
```

Comment: Creating objects just to run replace is going to be really slow. You're better of doing this in a simple loop.

Comment: Charlie, thank you so much for your feedback. I will try using functions and compare times.

Answer (score 1):

Following Charlie's suggestion, I rewrote the conversion using Functions instead of a Class and then tried processing a million items in a csv file using the Class and  Functions methods. Results:

- The Function and the Class methods used equivalent amount of CPU and memory
- The Class method was 9.4% slower than using Functions

Functions win. Thank you Charlie!

The Function method is below:

```
import csv
import openpyxl

#
# Convert the data in csv file format that contains a mix of
# strings, integers and dollar amounts into xlsx file format
#

csvfile  = 'large_test_export.csv'
xlsxfile = 'new_xlsx_f.xlsx'

wb = openpyxl.Workbook()
ws = wb.active

# remove $ and , from numbers

def strip_stuff(a_string):
    try:
        temp = a_string.replace(',','')
    except TypeError as err:
        print(err)      
    
    try:
        temp2 = temp.replace('$','')
    except TypeError as err:
        print(err)      

    try:
        temp3 = float(temp2)
        return temp3
    except ValueError as err:
        return temp2


def is_number(b_string):
    temp = strip_stuff(b_string)
    try:
        float (temp)
        return True
    except ValueError:
        return False

with open(csvfile) as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter=',', quotechar='"')
    row_count=1
    for row in reader:
        for i in range(len(row)):
            if is_number(row[i]):
                content = strip_stuff(row[i])
            else:
                content = row[i]                
            ws.cell(row=row_count,column=i+1).value = content
        row_count +=1

wb.save(xlsxfile)

print('Finished!')
```

Comment: This is still very inefficient. In a CSV file the structure should be regular so you should be able to run specific code for specific columns.

Comment: I agree it's not ideal. However the source data is input by thousands of independent people and the 3rd party company in charge of storing the source data doesn't enforce strict rules on what each column should contain. They just store numbers as strings. Consequently there's strings and numbers with a variety of formats (int, $, %) and I've found that I have to resolve these issues in order to do processing on them. So ist das Leben :)

Comment: You're still calling the functions too many times.